# How to check at runtime if an object is currently being used by the application, or has been garbage-collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, object-reference

The question pretty much says it all. Somewhere in my code i instantiated an object `ObjectX` with the `new` keyword. Now `ObjectX` is an expensive one in terms of memory and other resources. I need a means to check at runtime whether `ObjectX` is currently alive and being used by the application, or has been garbage-collected.
Any attempt to use a reference to the object is gonna make the object being used. So how can do i that?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx).

Comment: never used `WeakReference` before, but i think that's what i'm looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could keep a [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) to it. That won't stop it from being garbage collected, and you can check its "liveness" with [`IsAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.isalive.aspx).

It's generally a bit of a design smell if you need this sort of thing though. *Why* do you need to perform this check?

Comment: That would be the only way to do it, if you had any other reference to it that would cause the GC to root the object and not let it be collected.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Well another possible option would be to have a finalizer which raised an event which you had a handler for. That would be nastier though.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Yes, that's true. Ick.

Comment: there is *no* design to produce the smell ;) it's for helping me in some testing scenario. thanks a lot.